# Python is raising a Type error upon calling its function with a callback functionn using javascript (in eel)

Tags: javascript, python, callback, arguments, eel

Im using eel in python 3.12.1 (Windows 11) inside a venv. What Im trying to implement is, using vlc, play a song, and have a function that returns the currently playing time when called.

I exposed a defined function that returns the current time obtained from vlc after the song is loaded and played.

The problem comes when I call the function using javascript.

Here's the code

```py
import vlc
import eel

audio_file # audio file path. for eg. D:\\TheGreatMusicFolder\VeryStupidSong.mp3

song = vlc.MediaPlayer(audio_file)

song.play() # the song plays

@eel.expose
def get_song_current_time():
    return song.get_time()
```

in the javascript file

```js
// Code that handles the icon changing of play/pause button
// eel.js is imported in the html file as instructed in eel's documentaion (in github)
const currentTime = document.getElementById("current_time_display");

let currentTimeValue = 0;

eel.get_song_current_time((result) => {
    currentTimeValue = result;
});

console.log(currentTimeValue);
```

for which when i run the python file (that initiates the eel and imports this vlc media playing file to start the song, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(THE FOLDER IN WHICH THIS PROJECT RESIDES)\env\Lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 318, in _process_message
    return_val = _exposed_functions[message['name']](*message['args'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: get_song_current_time() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

BTW here's my packages and ther versions used

```
bottle==0.12.25
bottle-websocket==0.2.9
cffi==1.16.0
Eel==0.16.0
future==0.18.3
gevent==23.9.1
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
greenlet==3.0.3
pycparser==2.21
pyparsing==3.1.1
python-vlc==3.0.20123
setuptools==69.0.3
whichcraft==0.6.1
zope.event==5.0
zope.interface==6.1
```

Comment: can you show the function get_song_current_time()

Comment: The parentheses in your function call look wrong. Check the examples in the documentation: https://github.com/python-eel/Eel#callbacks. For example, correct is `eel.js_random()(print_num)`. What you have is the equivalent of `eel.js_random((print_num))`, which would be wrong.

Comment: oops, im sorry, its the same function as above in python, i accidently used the wrong name to reproduce the error in my code here.

Comment: @slothrop but they define the function in javascript and accesed it in python, mine here is the other way around

Comment: Also, not familiar with eel, but in python `f(): ...` is not a thing. You are missing a `def` somewhere. Are we looking at real code you have tested? (I suppose that if the problem was a miising `def` you would have guessed. But then, that, plus the name mixup, seems to indicate that we are debugging one code, and you have another)

Comment: @KaminariKatt the docs say *"(It works exactly the same the other way around)."*

Comment: @slothrop `eel.get_song_current_time();(result) => { console.log(result); };` is this supposed to work, becuase i got no console logs about this at all as if it never ran

Comment: There should be no semicolon after `get_song_current_time()` because that terminates the statement. I don't do much JS, but it should be something like `eel.get_song_current_time()(result=>{console.log(result);});`

Comment: Key thing is that the syntax is `eel.foreign_func()(callback);` not `eel.foreign_func((callback));` or `eel.foreign_func();callback;`

Comment: @slothrop im not a js person too. btw your answer worked. Thanks a lot, i have been wondering for 3 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the eel function and invoke a callback on the result, the syntax should be:

```
eel.foreign_function(args_of_foreign_function)(callback);
```

That's to say: calling the eel-decorated function returns a callable, which can be called with a callback function as argument.

This is the same for Python and Javascript, but of course the semicolon is optional in Python.

Reference: [Eel documentation on callbacks](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel#callbacks).

Your original code did the equivalent of:

```
eel.foreign_function(callback);
```

That gave the error you saw, because `callback` was being supplied to the Python function itself, rather than to the object returned by the eel-wrapped Python function.

As you found and mentioned in the comments, the correct call in your case is:

```
eel.get_song_current_time()( result => {console.log(result);} );
```